# Swap class w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I make a conditional swap with jQuery on click. If certain class is present swap it to another, for example swap class "A" to "B".

```
<a href="#" id="clickMe"><span class="A"></span>link</a>
```

I've been trying this but it does not seem to work:

```
$(this).closest("span").toggleClass("A,B");
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) goes up the DOM tree, not down.

Use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) or [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find).

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#clickMe').click(function ()
    {
        $(this).children('span').toggleClass('a b');
        return false; // don't follow the link
    });
});
```

[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) expects multiple class names to be separated by spaces, not commas.

If you only want the class swap to happen once:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#clickMe').click(function ()
    {
        var $span = $(this).children('span:first');
        $span.toggleClass('a b', $span.hasClass('a'));
        return false; // don't follow the link
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, it can be dome more then once. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).closest("span").removeClass("A").addClass("B");
```

**Edit:** the above will forcibly replace class A with class B.  I think what you're looking for is to toggle between A and B every time the code runs, correct?  Try:

```
$(this).closest("span").toggleClass("A B");
```

Comment: Why not '$(this).find("span").removeClass("A").addClass("B");'?

Comment: `closest()` goes up the DOM tree, not down.

Comment: @Owen: because the OP's code contained `$(this).closest("span")`, and that piece of the code is not relevant to the task of swapping classes.