# Check if class is present w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check if a certain class is present in an element and if yes, create a variable for my function?

```
<a href="#" id="clickMe"><span class="A open"></span>link</a>
```

For example if class open is present I will create a varialbe "close".

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#clickMe').click(function ()
    {
        // if "open"
        var myVar = 'close';
        // else 
        var myVar = 'open';
    });
});
```

Comment: It's extremely easy to answer this question by looking at the jQuery documentation. Go to http://api.jquery.com/ and type 'class' into the search. The answer is the third item in the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap class w/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404198/swap-class-w-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, `hasClass` will do it:

```
var isOpen = $(this).hasClass('open') ? 'close' : 'open';
```

---

Note that with your specific example, you'll need something closer to:

```
var isOpen = $(this).find('span').hasClass('open') ? 'close' : 'open';
```

since `this` in your callback will refer to the `A` and your `open` class is on the `SPAN`

---

jQuery also has a `toggleClass` method that may or may-not be what you're looking for:

```
$(this).toggleClass('open');
```

For reference: [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) It's usually pretty quick to find what you're looking for.